# calling javascript in python?

Tags: javascript, python, function, ffi

essentially I am writing something based off of python and I would like to, in python, be able to get the result of a javascript function.

Lets say `function.js` has a bunch of functions inside it

If I have some python code, in it I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
val = some_js_function(param1,param2,...paramn)
```

now `some_js_function` would be a function from the `function.js` file. This would set the variable `val` in my Python code to the result of that JS function.

**How could I go about doing this? Or do I have to rawCode a FFI for javascript myself.**

Comment: Have a look at Pyjamas, an implementation of Python written in Javascript.

Comment: I want the opposite of that. I need to run javascript in python, not python in javascript

Comment: I believe it should still work, if it is like CPython, Jython and IronPython etc. in which you can embed Python in the implementation language, but also the implementation language in Python. However, I may be wrong, this is only an assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at some java script interpreter that has support for python. You can take a look at Rhino, Google's V8 ([pyV8](https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/)), or even [pynarcissus](https://code.google.com/p/pynarcissus/).

Example from `pyV8`,

```
>>> import PyV8
>>> ctxt = PyV8.JSContext()          # create a context with an implicit global object
>>> ctxt.enter()                     # enter the context (also support with statement)
>>> ctxt.eval("1+2")
```

Comment: would this allow me to run a previously written javascript function in python if given the file with the function and the function name? It is undlear in any of those sources and that is what I need

Comment: @RyanSaxe You could load the function and `eval` the function, or just load the function into the interpeter, you should read the docs here, https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/w/list

Answer (score 1):

You could start a subprocess that calls "node function.js" or any other interpreter.